# In SQL Server Reporting Services, how do I limit Previous function's scope to a group?

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, aggregate-functions

I am working on a report that gets, for example purpose, 5 columns from database.
Lets say ProductionCountry, Industry, ProductGroup, ProductId, Price.
I am grouping them on ProductionCountry, Industry and ProductGroup.
Visually its like this.
[image]

I have applied this expression to hide repetition of a group's column data
`=Previous(Fields!IndustryName.Value) = Fields!IndustryName.Value`
But the problem with that is, this expression considers previous value from previous group.
If you can see the 2 red boxes in the image for Taiwan, I would like to show Hardware and LCD Panels in Industry and ProductGroup columns respectively. But the expression would hide it.

Any one knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check more than one criteria as you go down the hierarchy of values so you'll need three Visibility-Hidden expressions:

For ProductionCountry:

```
=Previous(Fields!ProductionCountry.Value) = Fields!ProductionCountry.Value
```

For Industry:

```
=Previous(Fields!ProductionCountry.Value) = Fields!ProductionCountry.Value AND Previous(Fields!IndustryName.Value) = Fields!IndustryName.Value
```

For ProductGroup:

```
=Previous(Fields!ProductionCountry.Value) = Fields!ProductionCountry.Value AND Previous(Fields!IndustryName.Value) = Fields!IndustryName.Value AND Previous(Fields!ProductGroup.Value) = Fields!ProductGroup.Value
```

Comment: I am able to render report as you can see in the image. I have applied visibility conditions for all 3 columns. But the problem is, Industry and ProductGroup values for Taiwan would not show up as it is same as Previous fields from China. I dont want the expression to consider values from China group.

Comment: Yes, that is why for the Country you just need to check if the country is different, but for the Industry, you need to check both Country and Industry so if the Industry is the same but the Country changes, the Industry will be displayed. Similarly for ProductGroup where you need to check all three of Country, Industry and ProductGroup